# Python IDLE syntax coloring (highlighting) of print inconsistent?

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, python-idle

Is Python IDLE consistent regarding syntax coloring (highlighting) of print?

I tested using IDLE 2.7.2. Sometimes it recognizes as a keyword. Sometimes as built-in ( such as list() or tuple() ). Both of them are, IMHO, correct; so IDLE is inconsistent?

Let me know your opinion.

KW

Added a screenshot 2012 04 01 18:27 KST (April fool's day but the shot is true.)

[Link to my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZaoy.png)

How I made this:

- Second print will be built-in from the beginning.
- The last(=fourth) print is more tricky. First leave no blank line between the third and the fourth print. Then the fourth print is a keyword.
- If I put insertion point (=cursor) at the end of the third print and press [Enter] key, the fourth print finally becomes a built-in.

Please let me know if I can have some more positive feedback now :)

Comment: ya it would be nice if we could see some code where it is inconsistent so we can replicate it. Doesn't have to be a screenshot... maybe just a few examples.

Answer (score 0):

Without examples or screenshots there isn't really much we can do here, but if you really want great Syntax Highlighting and error detection I'd recommend using an IDE like PyCharm. It is not open source but it is the best Python IDE I've tried.

Comment: Per your suggestion, I uploaded a screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zZaoy.png Please let me know if you have any problem seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed: http://bugs.python.org/issue6528

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, could you please check this link? : http://i.stack.imgur.com/zZaoy.png

Comment: That particular error has not been fixed in the 2.x series, but it is in the latest 3.2 release.