# Python IDLE miscoloring with "print" statement

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, python-idle

[proof of point http://adams-site.x10.mx/v/python.png](http://adams-site.x10.mx/v/python.png)

You'll notice in this image the two print statements are different colours.

It doesn't really matter a great deal, I'm not really bothered, but I thought it would be nice to know why, or if this is just a bug.

(I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903220/python-idle-syntax-coloring-highlighting-of-print-inconsistent) link, but I really would like to know *why*.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the code responsible for syntax highlighting from ColorDelegator.py:

```
def any(name, alternates):
    "Return a named group pattern matching list of alternates."
    return "(?P<%s>" % name + "|".join(alternates) + ")"

def make_pat():
    kw = r"\b" + any("KEYWORD", keyword.kwlist) + r"\b"
    builtinlist = [str(name) for name in dir(__builtin__)
                                        if not name.startswith('_')]
    # self.file = file("file") :
    # 1st 'file' colorized normal, 2nd as builtin, 3rd as string
    builtin = r"([^.'\"\\#]\b|^)" + any("BUILTIN", builtinlist) + r"\b"
    comment = any("COMMENT", [r"#[^\n]*"])
    sqstring = r"(\b[rRuU])?'[^'\\\n]*(\\.[^'\\\n]*)*'?"
    dqstring = r'(\b[rRuU])?"[^"\\\n]*(\\.[^"\\\n]*)*"?'
    sq3string = r"(\b[rRuU])?'''[^'\\]*((\\.|'(?!''))[^'\\]*)*(''')?"
    dq3string = r'(\b[rRuU])?"""[^"\\]*((\\.|"(?!""))[^"\\]*)*(""")?'
    string = any("STRING", [sq3string, dq3string, sqstring, dqstring])
    return kw + "|" + builtin + "|" + comment + "|" + string +\
           "|" + any("SYNC", [r"\n"])
```

It builds up a large regular expression which it uses to match items to colour. In particular, the regex defined as `kw` will match a keyword (as defined by the [keyword module](http://docs.python.org/library/keyword.html)) anywhere it's found in the source file, while the regex defined as `builtin` will match a builtin (as discovered by scanning `__builtin__`) as long as it doesn't follow a period, quote, double-quote, backslash or hash symbol.

Now, there are a combination of factors at work to give the strange behaviour you see. First of all, in Python 2.7 `print` is both a keyword and a builtin. (I'm not sure why, but I imagine it might be to keep closer to Python 3.0 where `print` is obviously a builtin and not a keyword.) So a regex is constructed that can match print as either a keyword or a builtin. But why does it sometimes match as one and sometimes as the other?

The difference is due to the construction of the regex. At the start of a line, the `kw` regex matches from the first character and it matches before the rest can be considered. However, after the start of the line, the `builtin` regex actually matches a character earlier, because the first character it looks for is "any character that isn't a period, quote, double-quote, backslash or hash". Even though that character isn't included in the labelled group, it's still part of the match. So when `print` is preceded by a space or tab, the `builtin` regex matches first.

One way to fix this would be to use a negative lookbehind assertion, but such a complicated regular expression already makes me a bit nervous and I'm never sure which regex features can result in catastrophic performance degradation. A simpler fix is to filter out any builtins that are also keywords before constructing the regex, and that's exactly what has been done in Python 3.2.2, as described in the bug report linked to from the question you reference.

Comment: +1 for delving into IDLE's source code when I wasn't game to. :-) AIUI, `print` is a builtin in 2.7 to make `from __future__ import print_function` work - the `print()` function is always around, but the keyword shadows it; the future import turns the keyword off.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue6528) linked in the previous question you mention, IDLE was getting confused with `True`, `False`, and `None` which weren't keywords for a long while, but become keywords by Py3.0 - previous to becoming keywords, they were just names in the built-in global namespace. So, IDLE would, between different contexts, colour them as builtins or as keywords inconsistently.

`print` has undergone exactly the opposite transformation - it was a keyword up until 3.0, after which it is merely a builtin (since it is now a function, rather than a statement). So, IDLE colours it both ways, depending on how it resolves which one it thinks applies. This appears to be resolved by the same patch (which is only in 3.2 and on, not any 2.x branch) - `print` is coloured purple consistently.